# How to use bootstrap modal with django?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to create a list of items and each item has a button to click and update that item. I'm trying to use bootstrap modal for the update. I can get it working, the problem is when I hit the update button it does not work because it is not passing the pk to my URL, any ideas to solve this problem?

This is my view

```
class ResearcherExperienceListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Researcher
    template_name = 'researcher/researcher_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(ResearcherExperienceListView, self).get_queryset()
        queryset = Researcher.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        print(self.kwargs)
        return queryset
```

this is my template for my ListView

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}   
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 5%">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 ">
            <h1 class="title text-center">Experiencia em Areas de conhecimento</h1>
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Area de Conhecimento</th>
                        <th>Ações</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>                    
                    {% for item in object_list.experience.all %}        
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                {{item}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a data-toggle="modal" href="{% url 'researcher_experience_update' pk=item.pk %}" data-target="#{{item.pk}}" data-tooltip>
                                <i class="fa fa-edit fa-2x"></i>
                            </a>            
                            </td>
                         </tr>
                         <div class="modal fade " id="{{item.pk}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">                    
                            {% include "researcher/experiencetime_form.html" %}                           
                         </div>         
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

My view for update

```
class ResearcherExperienceUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = ExperienceTime
    form_class = ExpirienceTimeForm
```

This is my template for the update.

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h2 class="text-center card-title" style="padding-top:10px">Informações Gerais</h2>
        <form method="post" action="update/" style="padding:20px">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }}
            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Update" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

urls

```
re_path(r'^experience/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ResearcherExperienceListView.as_view(), name="researcher_experience"),
re_path(r'^experience/update/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ResearcherExperienceUpdateView.as_view(), name="researcher_experience_update"),
```

Comment: Please paste your urls.py here.

Comment: re_path(r'^experience/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ResearcherExperienceListView.as_view(), name="researcher_experience"),
re_path(r'^experience/update/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ResearcherExperienceUpdateView.as_view(), name="researcher_experience_update"),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your help guys

I did solve the problem using get_context_data to pass a pk then in my form action i did something like this action="/researcher/experience/update/{{pk}}/"
I don't know if it is right or not but it works for now